# How to change the input value in ionic alertController on keyPress event

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, dom-events, android-alertdialog

I have an alertBox to input a number. How can I restrict user to enter negative value (-) or if entered -2, how to remove - from the number?

```
async updateBalance(): Promise<void> {
const alert = await this.alertController.create({
  header: 'Update Balance!',
  inputs: [
    {
      name: 'addAmount',
      type: 'number',
      id:'inputAmount',
      placeholder: 'Enter Amount'
    }
  ],
  buttons: [
    {
      text: 'Add',
      cssClass: 'secondary',
      handler: (data) => {
        this.calculateBalance(data, true);
      }
    }
  ]
});
alert.present();
alert.addEventListener('keypress', this.checkNegativeInput);
}
checkNegativeInput(e) {
  if(e.charCode !== 45) {
    document.getElementById('inputAmount')
  }
}
```

This code is detecting the event but I am not able to change the value of input field.

Comment: So when I enter '-10' and press the add button, do u just want the value, do u want to display the -10 as 10?

Answer (score 1):

```
  async createAlert() {
    var alert = await this.alertController.create({
      header: 'Update Balance!',
      inputs: [
        {
          name: 'addAmount',
          type: 'number',
          id: 'inputAmount',
          placeholder: 'Enter Amount'
        }
      ],
      buttons: [
        {
          text: 'Add',
          cssClass: 'secondary',
          handler: (data) =>
            alert.inputs=[
              {
                name: 'addAmount',
                type: 'number',
                id: 'inputAmount',
                placeholder: 'Enter Amount',
                value: this.validateNumber(data.addAmount)
              }
            ]
            return false;
          }
        }
      ]
    });
    alert.present();
  }
```

This works, but it only displays once for some reason. The input array doesn't get changed the second time you click add button. Remove the `return false;` so the alert will close. I'd recommend doing this though:

```
  async createAlert() {
    var alert = await this.alertController.create({
      header: 'Update Balance!',
      inputs: [
        {
          name: 'addAmount',
          type: 'number',
          id: 'inputAmount',
          placeholder: 'Enter Amount'
        }
      ],
      buttons: [
        {
          text: 'Add',
          cssClass: 'secondary',
          handler: (data) =>
            alert.message="You can't enter negative numbers";
            return false;
          }
        }
      ]
    });
    alert.present();
  }
```

Comment: Yes, I Tried assigning the data back to the input using other methods didn't work ... this one WORKS GREAT!